# Understand the difference between "sich beschweren" und "sich beklagen"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference

For me both of these verbs roughly mean "to complain". Here are Duden entries for ["sich beschweren"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/beschweren) and ["sich beklagen"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/beklagen). The examples are not really helpful:

> Ich habe mich wegen dieser Angelegenheit schon oft beschwert.
>
> Ich habe mich bei ihm über diese/wegen dieser Ungerechtigkeit beklagt.

Could you please provide three groups of examples:

- A group where only "sich beschweren" can be used
- A group where only "sich beklagen" can be used
- A group where the usage is interchangeable

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### sich beschweren

Man beschwert sich bei jener Person, die mutmaßlich den beklagenswerten Zustand verursacht hat, oder die ein Unternehmen vertritt, das man für den Verursacher hält.

> Hans trug seinen soeben gekauften Wasserkocher zum Händler zurück und **beschwerte** sich lautstark darüber, dass er nicht funktionierte. Er forderte vom Händler ein Ersatzgerät.

Eine Beschwerde hat zwei Zwecke:

1. Man will erreichen, dass der Zustand, der zur Beschwerde geführt hat, beseitigt wird.
2. Man will seine Empörung darüber, dass es diesen Zustand überhaupt gibt, demjenigen ins Gesicht sagen, der (vermeintlich) die Schuld daran trägt.

### sich beklagen

Eine Klage ist nicht notwendigerweise an die Person gerichtet, die an der Situation schuld ist, die beklagt wird.

> Lisa weinte und **beklagte** sich bei ihrer besten Freundin darüber, dass ihr Mann sie betrogen hatte. Sonja nahm Lisa in den Arm und tröstete sie.

Lisa wurde von ihrem Mann verlassen, also ist er derjenige, der Lisa damit verletzt hat. Aber Lisa klagt ihr Leid Sonja, also jemandem, der damit nichts zu tun hat.

Wenn man sich über etwas beklagt, dann meist, weil man möchte, dass andere Menschen einem versichern, dass man zurecht empört, gekränkt, verletzt usw., ist. Man will verstanden und vielleicht auch getröstet werden. Man erwartet aber nicht, dass sich dadurch etwas am beklagten Zustand ändert.

Daher kann man sich auch über das schlechte Wetter beklagen, oder darüber, dass die Äpfel, die man soeben aus dem eigenen Garten geerntet hat, sauer sind. Darüber kann man sich bei niemandem beschweren, weil es keine Person gibt, der man die Schuld daran geben kann.

Comment: Gibt es auch so einen Unterschied, dass z.B **sich beklagen** stärker als **sich beschwerden** ist oder umgekehrt?

Comment: @AdInfinitum: Die beiden Begriffe bedeuten etwas verschiedenes. Wie soll da das eine stärker oder schwächer als das andere sein? Genau so gut könntest du fragen: »Ist *mieten* stärker als *stehlen*? Z.B. im Satz ›*Hans hat ein Auto gemietet/gestohlen*‹« - So eine Frage hat keinen Sinn.

Comment: Von deiner Antwort habe ich so verstanden. Die beiden Wörtern sind wie synonym aber mit wem du sprichst spielt eine Rolle. z.B wenn man sich beschwert, spricht man mit demjenigen, der dieses Problem verursacht hat aber wenn man sich beklagt, spricht man mit einer neutralen Person, die nichts mit diesem Problem zu tun hat.

Comment: @AdInfinitum: Es geht weniger darum, mit wem man spricht, als vielmehr darum, was man erreichen will. Beschweren: 1. Man möchte, dass die Ursache beseitigt wird, und 2. man möchte seine Empörung dem Verursacher ins Gesicht sage. Hingegen Beklagen: Die Mitteilung machen, dass einem ein Leid widerfahren ist.

Comment: Danke schön Hubert. Der Unterschied ist jetzt viel klarer für mich.

Answer (score 5):

This is not an easy one. I might not be able to provide everything you request, but I shall make a start. And I’ll leave the discussion of legal vocabulary to experts.

**Beklagen** often covers more the sense of *whining* or *airing one’s grievance*. **Sich beschweren** often describes a formal complaint, or at least one that is going to have consequences. Thus I would prefer:

> Ich beschwere mich beim Chef über eine Mitarbeiterin.

Although *beklagen* would be possible in that context, too. And I would prefer:

> Ich beklage mich oft über das Wetter in Heidelberg.

and one may answer:

> Beschwer dich bei St. Peter!

because Germans believe St. Peter makes the weather …

**Beklagen** also has a sense close to *mourn*, perhaps somewhat weaker. In this sense *sich beschweren* can not be used:

> Ich beklage den Tod meines Freundes.

Etymology might shed more light on this, since *Klage* is — outside legal contexts — a lament.

Comment: But a German would not say "bei Sankt Peter" sondern "bei Petrus".

Comment: I am a German. To me Sankt Peter, Petrus and heiliger Petrus are all allowed! There is even a humorous German saying "Heiliger Sankt Florian, verschon mein Haus, zünd' andere an!" @celtschk

Comment: I'm also German. ANd it's not the "Sankt", but the "Peter" which sounds wrong to me. As I know it, the saint is always called "Petrus", not "Peter". The "Sankt Florian" example is irrelevant because that's another Saint (of whom I wouldn't know another name than "Florian").

Comment: @celtschk Ich tippe auf regionale Differenzen. St. Peter ist weit verbreitet: http://www.stpeterau.at Selbst Orte heißen so. http://www.kath-heidelberg-sued.de

Answer (score 4):

*Beklagen* is simply saying, that you don’t like something. It perfectly possible, to use *beklagen* for the weather. It is unclear from the word, whether you expect any result (except compassion).

*Beschweren* implies that you complain about something, addressing a person responsible for the origin of your complaint, possibly also in a formal way (written form, registered mail) with the strong expectation, that something is done. So you would use *beschweren* for

- addressing the customer support of the vendor of some device, exhibiting different ways of malfunction
- the public transportation company, for ending service too early, for the excessive delay.

Comment: A bit more precisely on "beschweren": You adress a person either responsible for the cause of the complaint *or* the person responsible to remediate, which do not necessarily have to be the same person.

Comment: I agree with Markus. You can "sich beschweren" to the police about a theft. Although you can see the police as indirectly responsible for the crime because the police officers were not there to prevent it, the biggest responsible is undoubtly the thief.

Answer (score 0):

Ein Beklagen ist gegen etwa*s.* Die Ursache des Problem ist zum beispiel die Natur.

Ein Beschweren ist gegen etwa. Ein Person hat die Schuld oder zumindest, die Last der Befestigung.

Beklagen is to complain about some *thing.* The problem arises from "nature."

Beschweren is to complain about some *one.* A synonym could be to "accuse."

Comment: What do you want to say with "Ein Beschweren ist gegen etwa. Ein Person hat die Schuld oder zumindest, die Last der Befestigung."? Both sentences are incomprehensible to me.

Comment: @Hulk: "Both sentences are incomprehensible to me" is ein Beschweren. I've confused you, and it is my responsibility to clear things up. On the other hand, if you can't read my text because there is no light, that would be ein Beklagen. In which case, turn on the light.

Comment: I reckon that you used some electronic translator for _"die Last der Befestigung"_. I did so as well and got "the burden of fixing". I don't know whether that's a proper term but now I know what you meant. I'd rephrase your 2nd sentence to "Ein Beschweren ist gegen jemanden. Eine Person hat die Schuld oder zumindest die Aufgabe/Pflicht, Abhilfe zu schaffen." (the task/duty to remedy/repair/fix)

Comment: This answer does not cover the true difference between both verbs at all. Both beschweren and beklagen can be used to complain about things and people and beschweren does *not* mean accuse. Look at the other answers for a better explanation.